# Unable to add/update Annotation in Java 7

Tags: java, reflection, annotations, java-7, javassist

I am trying to dynamically add Annotation in Java 7. But it fails to so. Could use some help.

Following are the 2 ways I am taking. In both the approach, immediately after adding the new Annotation when I check, the class/field doesnt reflect it.

**1. Create new Annotation with javaassist**

```
    public void javaassist(String className, List<String> props) throws Exception{
         //pool creation 
         ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
         //extracting the class
         CtClass cc = pool.getCtClass(className);
         // create the annotation
         ClassFile ccFile = cc.getClassFile();
         ConstPool constpool = ccFile.getConstPool();
         
         AnnotationsAttribute attr = new AnnotationsAttribute(constpool, AnnotationsAttribute.visibleTag);
         
         for(String propName: props) {
             javassist.bytecode.annotation.Annotation annot = 
                     new javassist.bytecode.annotation.Annotation("org.hibernate.annotations.ColumnTransformer", constpool);
             annot.addMemberValue("read", new StringMemberValue("aes_decrypt("+propName+", 'mysecret')", ccFile.getConstPool()));
             annot.addMemberValue("write", new StringMemberValue("aes_encrypt(?, 'mysecret')", ccFile.getConstPool()));
             
             attr.addAnnotation(annot);
             
             //looking for the method to apply the annotation on
             CtField propField = cc.getDeclaredField(propName);
             // add the annotation to the method descriptor
             List<AnnotationsAttribute> atts= propField.getFieldInfo().getAttributes();
             System.out.println(atts);
             // propField.getFieldInfo().addAttribute(attr);             
             atts.add(attr);
             System.out.println(atts);
         }
    }
```

**2. Create new Annotation with Class.class.getDeclaredField("annotations")**

```
    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    private void withNew(Class clazz, List<String> props) throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
        Field fieldAnnotations = Class.class.getDeclaredField("annotations");
        fieldAnnotations.setAccessible(true);
        Map<Class<? extends Annotation>, Annotation> annotations = (Map<Class<? extends Annotation>, Annotation>) fieldAnnotations.get(clazz);
        for(String prop: props) {
            annotations.put(ColumnTransformer.class, this.buildColTransfAnnotation(prop, key));
        }
    }
    
    private Annotation buildColTransfAnnotation(final String propName, final String key) {
        return new ColumnTransformer() {
            @Override
            public Class<? extends Annotation> annotationType() {
                return ColumnTransformer.class;
            }
            
            @Override
            public String write() {
                return "aes_encrypt(?, '"+key+"')";
            }
            
            @Override
            public String read() {
                return "aes_decrypt("+propName+", '"+key+"')";
            }
            
            @Override
            public String forColumn() {
                return null;
            }
        };
    }
```

**Following is how I am verifying it**

```
    private void print(List<String> props) throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException {
        for(String propName: props) {
            Field field = Partner.class.getDeclaredField(propName);
            
            for(Annotation an: field.getAnnotations()) {
                System.out.println(an);
            }
        }
    }
```

Seems its something to do with Java 7.

Comment: Did you try to use `addAttribute` method of the `CtField` instead of dumping all the attributes in a list and add your new one to that list?

Comment: Yes, I tried addAttribute. The problem is same again i.e. During reflection run it works, but on app runtime it shows the Annotations are missing.
The same seems code seems to be working for Java 11.